# Change service account on google dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Google's documentation says that when we create a dataproc cluster it uses projects default service account.

source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataproc/clusters/create

Is it possible to use some other service account other than default one?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688545/using-non-default-service-account-in-google-cloud-dataproc. (And no, it's not possible at the moment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible at this time. You may also want to take care; you're looking at the docs for the `gcloud beta dataproc` command. If that is what you want then no big deal, but if you're just using `gcloud dataproc` then [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create) will be more helpful.

Comment: It's possible now: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts. see "Service accounts in Cloud Dataproc"